# Countability of S

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to find out whether the set $S = \{x \in \mathbb{R} | x = a + b\cdot\sqrt{2}, (a, b) \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is countable.

My initial thought was to prove that this is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, and that since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, then so is $S$, but just plugging $a = b = 1$ gives us $\sqrt{2}$, not a member of $\mathbb{Q}$. That idea quickly went out the window, and I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: Hint: The very definition of $S$ provides you with a useful function $f : \mathbb Z^2 \to S$.

Comment: @LeeMosher do you suggest just proving that trying to prove that f(a, b) = a + b*sqrt(2) from Z to S is a bijection would be enough?

Comment: That is not a bijection from $\Bbb Z$ to S. It is a bijection from $\Bbb Z^2$ to S. But yes, that is enough, if you are allowed to use the fact that $\Bbb Z^2$ is countable.